# Storing data for an instance of an interface

Tags: java, dictionary, storage

I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of storing values (like fields) for an instance of an interface (if implementing it is not guaranteed) than a static hashmap in an other non-visible class.

Example:

```
public interface myInterface {

    public default Object getMyVariable() {
        return Storage.data.get(this);
    }

}

final class Storage {

    static HashMap<myInterface, Object> data = new HashMap<myInterface, Object>();

}
```

Comment: That's horrible, why would you do that? And if you need `data` why wouldn't you put it in `myInterface`? But why do you need the `Map` in the first place?

Comment: because I it to act as if it was private

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all this is bad bracrice - you abstraction knows about implementations. The point of interface is to introduce abstraction - and get rig of *rigit* design.

You can define interface like that:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    default Object getMyVariable() {
        return getDefaultObject();
    }

    Object getDefaultObject()
}
```

As you can see i added *required* method `getDefaultObject()` - that all implementations have to implement. However this will not work if you already have implementation classes - and you have no control over them.

Comment: I am making this rigit on purpose because I want to this make this feature like a class (I know that's not possible), but the classes I would like to implement it are already extending another.